# nuxt can I manually show the loading indicator?

Tags: nuxt.js

I would like to use the loading indicator that is displayed in nuxt when I navigate between routes for all my ajax calls.

Can I somehow trigger the indicator to show?

Comment: Did you find any solutions? Please share. I need it on my project. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
methods: {
  async onSubmit() {
    try {
      this.$root.$loading.start();
      const result = await someAsyncMethod();
    } catch (err) { 
      // this.$toast.error(err.message);
    } finally { 
      this.$root.$loading.finish(); 
    }
},
```

This could be a typical async method using the default loading indicator.

Comment: Thanks! How is the $root object accessed in vuex, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In new versions, it's this.$nuxt.loading.start()

```
methods: {
  search() {
    this.$nuxt.$loading.start() //STARTS LOADING
    this.$axios
      .get('/api/product')
      .then((response) => {
        this.$nuxt.$loading.finish() //STOPS LOADING
        this.results = response.data
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.$store.commit('snackbar/add', err.response.data)
    })
  }
}
```

**NOTE**

If you have set `dark` to `false` then the progress bar will be showing in white color and in white background, it will not be visible. remember to change the color of progress in nuxt.config.js